# Backward delete till character in Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> deletes till the next comma.

```
a, b, c[,] d, e

dt,

a, b, c[,] e
```

What is the command to perform same operation in backward direction in order to get:

```
a, b, d, e
```

Comment: if you type `dt,`, you got `a.. c,, e`  what do you really want? your example doesn't work like what you said. you mean `df,` ?

Comment: In normal mode, the cursor is always *on* a character. I'd suggest you edit your question like this to clarify it a little: `a, b, c[,] d, e`.

Comment: The cursor is on the comma character. Edited question to clarify this

Answer (score 73):

Often in Vim, the capitalised letter performs the motion in the opposite direction. Thus <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> will do the search backwards. However, you need to use <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> so that the first comma is deleted.

For the same reason you need to use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> instead of <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to delete the comma in your given example.

Comment: I'm not sure about doing what OP wants, because his example for `dt` is wrong (`dt` wouldn't delete comma itself). Maybe `df` and `dF` are closer.

Comment: @PrinceGoulash df, includes ending ','. dt, is what works in the forward direction. dF, works in the backward direction. Thanks